# Img slider - next or prev img src based on a "clicked" img from an array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I m new to web design, this is what I wanted (works up to a point): I have this array of small imgs displayed (in #image-holder ) and each img u click on, it opens in another tag (in #bigimg) at full size. I also managed to make a slider(in #bigimg) of all the images(full size) in the array. U can go back and forth by clicking on buttons. What I cant do is "get" the specific src of the *clicked* img, so that by clicking "next" button will idd show the next(of *that*) img in the array [ and "prev" button will show the actually previous(of *that*) img]. Here is my code so far:

```
    var images=new Array();
    var i;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("image_slider.php", function(json) {
                for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
                {
                    images[i]="images/"+json[i];

                   $('<img>').attr('src',images[i]).css({"width":"60px", "padding":"5px"}).appendTo('#image-holder');
                }
                var theimgs= document.getElementById("image-holder").getElementsByTagName("img") ;
                for (i in theimgs)
                {
                    theimgs[i].onclick=function (){     
                            getimg (this) ;}    
                }  
                }); 
        }); 
    function getimg (z){
        var n=document.getElementById("bigimg") ;
        n.src= z.src ; }

    var x=0 ;
    function getall_next (){
        x++; 
        var n=document.getElementById("bigimg") ;
        n.src=images[x] ;
        if (x==images.length)
        {
            x=0 ;
            n.src=images[0] ;
        } }
    function getall_prev (){
        var n=document.getElementById("bigimg") ;
        if (x==0)
        {
            x=images.length ;
            n.src=images[images.length] ;
            x-- ;   
        }
        else
            x-- ;
        n.src=images[x] ; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okies, after a lot or research and trial&error, I finally found the solution :P Here is my code working perfectly now, plus a very useful link which helped me http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-css3-lightbox-tutorial . I had to adjust it -I use php to get images from a folder- so here it is:

```
    var images=new Array();
    var i;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("MY_img_array.php", function(json){
            for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
            {
                images[i]="images/"+json[i];
                $('<img>').attr('src',images[i]).css({"width":"60px", "padding":"5px"}).appendTo('#imgarray');
            }       
            $("#imgarray img").click(function() {
                    $("#imgarray img.active").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    var large_img = new Image();
                    large_img.src = this.src;
                    $('div#bigimg').html(large_img);
                });

            $("#prevbtn").click(function(){ navigate(-1) });
            $("#nextbtn").click(function(){ navigate(1) });
            function navigate(direction) {
                if(direction == -1) // left
                    $("#imgarray img.active").prev().trigger("click");
                else if(direction == 1) //right
                    $("#imgarray img.active").next().trigger("click");
                }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `jquery` you can do all this with less code, but since your using plain javascript

```
var image_src = document.getElementById("bigimg").src;
```

base  on your response here is some pseudo code.

```
//when you set the bigimg 
   last_image = bigimg.src;
   bigimg.src = newimg;
   current_image = newimg;

 //then before setting new img you 
 //you can access those variables you set above
```

Comment: #bigimg already receives a src with getimg(z) --> when clicking on one of the small imgs in #image-holder. I believe my mistake is when setting x=0 just before the getall_next and getall_prev functions, cause then the n.src=images[x] messes it all up. I need to somehow connect the last src received for #bigimg (last small img clicked) with the next or prev img src in my array, otherwise when clicking on next/prev buttons, the "slider" starts from the beginning and not from the random-clicked img. Thanx for the quick reply, I get it that u store the src but I cant see how to proceed :S

Comment: Hm at some point this helps at some point I still get confused, I ll look at it again tomorrow, my eyes are complaining... Thank u very much!

Comment: Ok, here is the thing: ur logic sounds suitable, except for one thing: x refers to the "position" of an element in an array. So what i need is not only to get the src of the last clicked img, but more important, its position ( i=?) in the array images[i]. This is what i ve been trying to do without success :S